# Reset page number after is not working in Crystal reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a main report which contains two sub-reports. These sub-reports are placed in report-footer A and report-footer B. Now I want to reset page numbering after first sub-report.

In the section expert I have checked the "reset page number after" option. But still I have continuous page numbering for both the sub-reports combined.

Please help.

Comment: Which section contains the PageNumber field?

Comment: Did you checked the "reset page number after" for the right section? (report footer A). Try checking that for both footers.

Comment: The page number field is in page footer section.. @Urik Yes I have checked in Report footer A. Also tried chceking for both report footers but still have the same problem

Comment: Did you try to check the "reset page number after" for all the sections? Maybe something will change and give you a hint...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.. problem is solved :)

Subreport in report footer A had a 'new page before' checked in its report footer section. Once this tick was removed, page number problem got resolved. 
Though m not getting how the subreports new page after affected page numbering in main report.